# How do I figure out why a certain user was put in the penalty box?

Tags: discussion, support

I just noticed a rather prominent user has 1 reputation. That seemed weird, so I visited his/her profile page only to learn about the ["penalty box"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) (which I had not encountered before). I'm curious to find out why that user was put in the box (and for quite a long period of time, too). How can I figure this out other than asking him/her?

I couldn't decide whether I want this question to be general or about this specific case with that specific user; I've chosen the former, so please don't make your answer about that person if you can guess who I mean. I will also mention I don't know him personally and have not even chatted or exchanged comments with him before.

Comment: Suspensions are between a user and a moderator and are not discussed in public unless the user chooses to do so. If they have their contact details in their profile you are free to contact them in private.

Comment: @rene: But doesn't the suspension follow some visible behavior on the site, e.g. on some questions? Or can you be suspended for, say, some comment you made in chat that will be difficult to find ex-post-facto?

Comment: You can be suspended for everything that is deemed abusive/rude behavior and that comes in all kind of forms, from fraud, till harassment and yes, if that happened in public then moderators will clean-up.

Comment: Suspensions are handed out by moderators based on information we have about a user, much of which is not public. Please don't assume that what you *can* see publicly is the whole picture.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Not assuming, just asking.

Comment: I'm just pre-empting wild guesses. Moderators will usually clean up if a user behaved in a way worthy of suspension in public, for example.